# Java format BigDecimal numbers with comma and 2 decimal place

Tags: java, formatting, decimal, bigdecimal

I want to format BigDecimal Numbers with comma and 2 decimal points. 
e.g.

```
Amount is: 5.0001 and formatted to: 5.00
Amount is: 999999999.999999 and formatted to: 999,999,999.99
Amount is: 1000.4999 and formatted to: 1,000.49
Amount is: 9999.089 and formatted to: 9,999.08
Amount is: 0.19999 and formatted to: 0.19
Amount is: 123456.99999999 and formatted to: 123,456.99
```

Answer (score 18):

This should be enough to get the results.

```
String.format("%,.2f", amount.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN));
```

Comment: Output depends on locale, so maybe use `format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%,.2f", amount.setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN))`. If you change locale to `FRANCE` you will see little different formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `DecimalFormat`:

```
val df: DecimalFormat = DecimalFormat("#,##0.000")
df.decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault())
df.format(BigDecimal(123456,78)); //will output 123.456,78 - depending on Locale
```